# Ambiguous type variable `a0' arising from a use of `it'

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, ghc, ghci, ambiguous-type-variable

I have the following function to return the Factor Pairs for a given number

```
factorPairs:: (RealFrac a, Floating a, Integral a) => a -> [(a, a)]
factorPairs n = map(\x -> (x, div n x)) [y | y <- [1..(ceiling $ sqrt n)], n `rem` y == 0]
```

When I call the function in ghci `factorPairs 18` I'm getting a run time error of

```
   * Ambiguous type variable `a0' arising from a use of `it'
      prevents the constraint `(Floating a0)' from being solved.
      Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what `a0' should be.
      These potential instances exist:
        instance Floating Double -- Defined in `GHC.Float'
        instance Floating Float -- Defined in `GHC.Float'
    * In the first argument of `print', namely `it'
      In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it
```

I can hard code the function in ghci

`` map(\x -> (x, div 18 x)) [y | y <- [1..(ceiling $ sqrt 18)], 18 `rem` y == 0] ``
 and don't have any issues but I can't seem to figure out why my function is failing. I believe ghci is trying to tell me it can't figure out what type to call `print` with but am struggling to find the solution.

Comment: Try ":t map(\x -> (x, div 18 x)) [y | y <- [1..(ceiling $ sqrt 18)], 18 `rem` y == 0]" on GHCi to find out the inferred type.

Comment: You should reconsider your type signature. Can you name a type that is both `Floating` and `Integral`?   I suggest you make the function monomorphic, ex use `Double`, and generalize only when needed.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson I was actually thinking about that for fun: is there ever any _reasonable_ type that is both `Floating` and `Integral`? Also, is there a way of searching for types based on instances the way we can use hoogle or hayoo to search for functions based on types?

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson I arrived at that type signature by not declaring one, and  then calling :t factorPairs. Can you elaborate what you mean by making it monomorphic. Changing the constraint to simply Double doesn't compile

Comment: Indeed, it doesn't compile.  That leaves you with another step before it functions and a type error that helps direct where to look.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This has to do with the fact numeric literals are overloaded in Haskell. When you type `` map(\x -> (x, div 18 x)) [y | y <- [1..(ceiling $ sqrt 18)], 18 `rem` y == 0] `` into `ghci`, the `18` that is an argument to `sqrt` defaults to a `Double` and the others to `Integer`s.

However, when you write

```
factorPairs:: (RealFrac a, Floating a, Integral a) => a -> [(a, a)]
factorPairs n = map(\x -> (x, div n x)) [y | y <- [1..(ceiling $ sqrt n)], n `rem` y == 0]
```

you force all instances of `n` to have only one type. Then, the problem becomes that there simply are no default number types (in fact number types in general I think) that satisfy all of these constraints, hence GHC telling you about "possible instances" it tries. The solution is to add `fromIntegral` and loosen the constraints:

```
factorPairs:: Integral a => a -> [(a, a)]
factorPairs n = map(\x -> (x, div n x)) [y | y <- [1..(ceiling $ sqrt $ fromIntegral n)], n `rem` y == 0]
```

Answer (score 4):

Another way to get rid of the type error is to eliminate the use of `sqrt`. Since Haskell is lazy, you can simply iterate over `[1..n]`, stopping when your divisor is greater than your quotient.

```
factorPairs :: Integral a => a -> [(a, a)]
factorPairs n = takeWhile (uncurry (>=)) [ (n `div` d, d) | d <- [1..n], n `mod` d == 0]
```

`uncurry (>=)` is just a fancy way of writing `\(q, d) -> q >= d`.

If you write this in monadic form, you can use `divMod` to get the quotient and the remainder with a single function all.

```
factorPairs n = takeWhile (uncurry (>=)) $ do
                d <- [1..n]
                let (q, r) = n `divMod` d
                guard $ r == 0
                return (q, d)
```