# Haskell. Type error when loading function but not inline

Tags: haskell

I'm a complete newbie to Haskell.  I type this into WinGHCi and it works fine:

```
> let x = 0.5
> let n = 5
> map (\y->(x**y)) [0..n]
[1.0,0.5,0.25,0.125,6.25e-2,3.125e-2]  -- notice it is powers of 1/2 !
```

But when I define a simple function in a file:

```
powersOfx :: (Integral a, Floating b) =>  a -> b -> [b]
powersOfx n x = map (\y->(x**y)) [0..n]
```

and type
`:l myFile`, I get:

```
 Couldn't match expected type ‘b’ with actual type ‘a’
      ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          powersOfx :: forall a b. (Integral a, Floating b) => a -> b -> [b]
```

What's going on? Am I doing the signature incorrectly?  I'm guessing I might be, because when I just comment it out and :l myFile it works but

```
:t powersOfx
```

I get:

```
powersOfx :: (Floating b, Enum b) => b -> b -> [b]
```

Notice the 'Enum' instead of 'Integral'.

I suppose I could just get rid of the type signature but I'm under the impression it's good practice to put a signature AND I'm trying to solve a larger problem where I'm getting error reported here:
[Ambiguous type variable `a0' arising from a use of `it'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38531803/ambiguous-type-variable-a0-arising-from-a-use-of-it)

If I get this part working, I'll post a separate question about that!

Please let me know if I'd be better off posting to another group or if I should be posting more information.

-Dave

Comment: It has to be an `Enum` because otherwise you can’t have the operation `[0..n]`. As for the `Floating` – the operands of `**` have to both be the same type. Maybe you’re looking for the `^` operator? Also, `powersOf x = map (x^) [0..]` and you can `take 5 (powersOf 0.5)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## The signature of the `map (\y->(x**y)) [0..n]` function

**In short:** your signature is **too broad**, one can design `Floating` types such that the function can not be called.

Let us first analyze the types you use here:

```
Prelude> let x = 0.5
Prelude> let n = 5
Prelude> :t map (\y->(x**y)) [0..n]
map (\y->(x**y)) [0..n] :: (Enum b, Floating b) => [b]
Prelude> :t \n x -> map (\y->(x**y)) [0..n]
\n x -> map (\y->(x**y)) [0..n]
  :: (Enum b, Floating b) => b -> b -> [b]
```

So what we see here is that the output type `b`, actually has to be an instance of two typeclasses: `Enum`, and `Floating`. That is logical: you use `[0..n]`, so that means that you ask Haskell to enumerate all elements between `0` and `n`, but a number is not per se enumerable (in fact we can already wonder that `Floating` is `Enum`erable in the first place: here we make hops of one, but we thus omit the `Floating` values in between, in case we would have a real float, then enumerating is even impossible).

As a result the `y`s have the same type as `n`, and since we perform arithmetic with `x` and `y` (we write `x ** y`), this thus means that `x` and `y` need to have the same type since `(**)` has type [**`(**) :: Floating a => a -> a -> a`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-42--42-). We can thus construct a function:

```
powersOfx :: (Enum b, Floating b) => b -> b -> [b]
powersOfx n x = map (\y->(x**y)) [0..n]
```

But this is a bad idea. `Floating` is usually something we better avoid as much as possible: if the number is large, we can have all sorts of rounding errors. We could use [**`fromIntegral :: (Integral a, Num b) => a -> b`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:fromIntegral), but again this can result in rounding errors when we convert for example a large `Int` to a `Float`. In that case the type would be:

```
powersOfx :: (Enum b, Floating b, Integral a) => a -> b -> [b]
powersOfx n x = map (\y->(x**y)) [0..fromIntegral n]
```

## Making a more generic variant

Nevertheless we can make the function more flexible and generic, by using [**`iterate :: (a -> a) -> a -> [a]`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:iterate) and by using the [**`take :: Int -> [a] -> [a]`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:take) (or [**`genericTake :: Integral i => i -> [a] -> [a]`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:genericTake)):

```
import Data.List(genericTake)

powersOfx :: (Integral i, Num n) => i -> n -> [n]
powersOfx n x = genericTake (n+1) (iterate (x*) 1)
```

This then produces:

```
Prelude Data.List> f 5 0.5
[1.0,0.5,0.25,0.125,6.25e-2,3.125e-2]
```

Comment: Thanks Willem. Two comments. 1) I get an error of error: parse error on input ‘import’
when I try your example.  2) The larger question.  I appreciate your example, but how would one get my original method working?  As I said, it works fine when you type it directly into WinGHCi but produces the error described with a ":load".  I tried changing the signature to powersOfx :: (Enum a, Floating b) =>  a -> b -> [b] and got the same error as when I used Integral.

Comment: (1) that is probably because you defined functions before the `import` statement. `import` statements should be grouped at the top (2) By changing the signature to the one above; but that would make the function just horrible, since then `n` is considered to be a `Floating`, and those typically can have rounding errors. You can start converting between `Integral`s with `fromIntegral`, but that again can result in rounding errors. The signature is `:: (Enum b, Floating b) => b -> b -> [b]` (note here there is only `b`, not `a`).

Comment: Thank you very much Wilem!  It's becoming clearer. I reread your answer, and (hopefully correctly) inferred what your answer implies. 1) Yes, I put import ant beginning of file and all is well.  2) Once I put all 'b' and not some combination of 'a' and 'b' in :: (Enum b, Floating b) => b -> b -> [b] all worked.  I was assumming that there had to be an 'a' and a 'b' because there are two arguments, n and x.  But the Enum b, Floating b is referring to the fact that both arguments need to be floating and enum. I see why both have to be floating (because I used **) but not why both need enum.